# Camera not working using phonegap build

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm making an app capable of take photos and upload them to a server. The phone will save the id generated.

I made a class abstractApp that creates an App object with a couple of helpers and variables. I'm using Framework7.

```
var App;


document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
App = new abstractApp();
var i;

App.f7Ref = new Framework7({init: false});

for (i = 0; i < App.constants.views.length; i++)
{
    if (i==0)
        App.mainView = App.f7Ref.addView (
            App.constants.views[i].selector,
            App.constants.views[i].settings );

    else
        App.f7Ref.addView (
            App.constants.views[i].selector,
            App.constants.views[i].settings );

}

// Checks if there exists register of remote photos
if ( App.local.get('remotephotos', false) == null || App.local.get('remotephotos', false) == '' )
{
    App.remotephotos = [];
    App.local.set('remotephotos', []);
}
else
{
    App.remotephotos = App.local.get('remotephotos');
}

// Checks if there exists register of local photos
if ( App.local.get('localphotos', false) == null || App.local.get('localphotos', false) == '' )
{
    App.localphotos = [];
    App.local.set('localphotos', []);
}
else
{
    App.localphotos = App.local.get('localphotos');
}


for (i = 0; i < appControllers.length; i++)
{
    appControllers[i].apply(App);
}

console.log(App);

}, false);
```

In appControllers I'm saving functions related to each page (so it is a bit more organized). With only index and new-photo controllers I have no problem, I can attach events to elements and navigate between views. The problem is calling the camera object.

```
window.appControllers.push(function()
{
    var $$      = Dom7;
    var Ref     = this.f7Ref;
    var server  = new serverInterface();
    var photos  = this.remotephotos;

    var App = this;

    Ref.onPageInit('new', function (page) {
        Ref.alert('entra', 'entra');
        $$('.capture').on('click', function () {

        Ref.alert('Click', 'Click detected');

        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail,
        { 
            quality: 20,
            destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI
        }); 

        function onSuccess(imageURI) {
            Ref.alert('Photo captured.', 'Bien');
        }

        function onFail(message) {
            Ref.alert('There was a problem.', 'Ups');
        }


        });
    });




});
```

So, I enter the new page and I click the button with cass capture and the alert (click detected) appears, but it doesn't show the camera to take the photo.

I'm using Phonegap Build and an android phone, do you have any idea of what's happening?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't the javascript code I quoted.

I was loading the camera plugin in the config.xml like this

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
```

But it should be loaded this way:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera"  />
```

If the plugin is not loaded correctly, in Phonegap Build appears: version n/a installed. In this case, when it is correctly loaded, appears: version 2.1.0 installed.

More information about this thread can be found here: http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/11/19/config_xml_changes_part_two/

Hope it helps someone else too

Regards